# Danish character not supported

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, globalization

I am working on a site thath has to also support Danish characters (the supported languages will increase in the future).

I am using a database table - lets call it `Strings` - where I create a record for each string I display on my site. For example, the greeting message in the login page is entered in the database like this:

> ID | Description | Text | Lang_code
>
> 1  |   login   | Log In |  en

This is the code that pulls the lang_code from the database:

```
Public Shared Function GetLanguageCodeFromBrowser()
        Dim language_code As String
        Dim databaseConnection As New DBConnectionAdapter
        Dim DataReader, DataReader1 As MySqlDataReader

        Dim serverVar As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE")

        language_code = LCase(serverVar)



        Dim Query As String = "SELECT language_code FROM languages WHERE language_code = '" & LCase(language_code) & "' AND disabled = 0"
        Dim Query1 As String = "SELECT language_code FROM languages WHERE language_code = '" & LCase(Left(language_code, 2)) & "' AND disabled = 0"

        Dim cmdSelect As New MySqlCommand(Query, databaseConnection.connectionWebServices)
        Dim cmdSelect1 As New MySqlCommand(Query1, databaseConnection.connectionWebServices)

        Try
            databaseConnection.OpenWebServices()
            DataReader = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader

            If Not DataReader.Read Then
                DataReader.Dispose()

                DataReader1 = cmdSelect1.ExecuteReader

                If Not DataReader1.Read Then
                    DataReader1.Dispose()
                    Return language_code = "en"
                Else

                    Return DataReader1("language_code")
                End If
                DataReader1 = Nothing
                DataReader1.Dispose()
            Else

                Return DataReader("language_code")
            End If
            DataReader = Nothing
            DataReader.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' TODO Error handling
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ex.Message)
        Finally

            databaseConnection.CloseWebServices()

        End Try

        databaseConnection = Nothing

    End Function
```

And I use it in the MasterPage's Page_Init event like this:

```
Session("language_code") = Language_from_Browser.GetLanguageCodeFromBrowser
```

Everything works fine in English, but when it comes to Danish, some characters are mangled.

I have tried changing this in web.config:

```
<globalization
      fileEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
      requestEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
      responseEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
      culture="auto"
      />
```

Still not working properly.

Please note that I have a `default.aspx` page in each one of my folders, so I dont have to bother with URL rewriting (that's how I see it a least)

Comment: I can see a couple of errors in your code which Visual Studio would point out to you if you used [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx).

Comment: You are right, errors did pop up, but not in the code I described above.

Comment: The function declaration is missing `As String`, consequently where you have `Return language_code = "en"` it will return `True` or `False`, depending on the value of `language_code`. I suspect that is not what you wanted. Although I don't think that will fix the immediate problem, it may lead you to where the problem is.

Comment: I will look into that and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried doing everything with `utf-8`? Also, [ASP.NET Globalization and Localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) could be useful to you.

Comment: Yes I tried that. This system was already built in classic asp and part of the migration process was to keep the way it handles translation (strings in the database pull by a method using the language code).

Comment: Are you sure the browser is using the correct charset, e.g. by having `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />` in the `<head>` section? Have the strings in the database been converted to UTF-8?